# Is there a way to use RequireJS when importing VueJS components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, requirejs

I have a project which uses RequireJS and Vue components. I am trying to modularise the Vue components into smaller parts and I want to be able to export smaller vue components so that they can be used by a bigger one. This is simple with standard vue:

```
import SomeComponent from './SomeComponent.vue'

new Vue({
     el: '#app',
     ...
     components: { SomeComponent },
     ...
}
```

but how would this be done with requireJS?

Comment: What do you mean by with requireJS? Use require.js instead of webpack? If so (or not), Can you show an example of how that could be? (syntax-wise)

Comment: Please show your require.js configuration.  Are you sure you are not confusing the AMD loader, require.js for the CommonJS or even async `import` syntax?

Comment: Please provide code for `SomeComponent.vue` or at least, a sample reflecting what you have

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `require` to import your `*.vue` components like this:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  ...
  components: {
    'some-component': require('../path/to/components/SomeComponent.vue').default,
    ...
  },
  ...
});
```

Your `*.vue` files should be structured like this:

```
<template>

  <!-- Component HTML  -->

</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'some-component',
    ...
  }
</script>

<style>
  
  /* Component Styles */

</style>
```

As an alternative, you can use `require` to register you components globally ([see api docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-component)):

```
Vue.component('some-component', require('../path/to/components/SomeComponent.vue').default);

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  ... // no need to declare `SomeComponent` here
});
```

This is a good option if you have several components that will all make use of `SomeComponent`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've also found that you can use this plugin https://github.com/edgardleal/require-vuejs which lets you use a vue as a module which can be then imported by
    `define(["vue!./path/to/vue/SomeComponent"], function (SomeComponent) {
         ...
    }`

Comment: The `.default` saved me. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I'm not exactly certain what you are asking, but if you are just trying to modularize, you can do this with import.  The way to do this is by importing components into components.

If you have a pagination component that is being imported to your app, you can import a smaller component (a sub-component) into pagination component.  You can go as small as you want this way and have sub-sub-sub-components.  The syntax for importing components into components is identical to importing components into a new vue page.

Unless I'm missing something, there's no reason to try and use require.  Vue already gives you everything you need with the ability to import components.  That's the proper way to modularize and keep your code DRY in Vue.

Comment: This "answer" does not answer the OP's question. Maybe the OP is adding Vue components to an existing codebase which uses `require` statements rather than `import` statements. It makes sense that the OP would want to be consistent with the existing code. But regardless of OP's reason for wanting to do it this way, this is not an answer to the question that was asked.

Comment: This is what the OP asked: " I am trying to modularise the Vue components into smaller parts and I want to be able to export smaller vue components so that they can be used by a bigger one."  He explicitly says that he wants to export smaller vue components into a "bigger one", meaning a bigger vue component (I assume).  The question is not clear, but my answer adequately deals with the question as asked.

Comment: OP also explicitly shows that he/she understands exactly how this is done using `import` statements. Your answer adds nothing.